# cUrl multiple URL open

Tags: php, mysql, curl

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `chat` LIMIT 0, 24334436743;'; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
$URL = $row['url'];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"$URL");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user=unrevoked clarity&randominfo=hi");
curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
   }





//curl_close ($ch);
}
```

Alright the above snippet is me pulling a whole bunch of URL's from a database and I am trying to send data to each of them. But it seems to gum the page up (even with only one or two URL's). Is there a built in system to handle this or something?

Comment: Could you use ajax requests to break it up, so your page can be responsive and load results/progress as a request completes.

Comment: I am writing a chat script but all the nodes are on different servers. Basically node hits this script this script distributes to other nodes. No way around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize multiple requests using the [curl_multi_*() functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php), then have them sent all at once. There is probably a limit to how many requests can be pooled. And the overall processing time will take as long as the slowest connection/server.

So your approach (many many URLs at once) is still problematic. Maybe you can rewrite it to do the processing in your browser, start multiple AJAX requests with some visual feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Requesting a URL from the network is an expensive operation, and even downloading a few will noticeably increase the latency of your page. Can you cache the contents of the pages in a database? Do you have to download the URL; can you make the client do it with an iframe?